# Help me identify game from 90s

Tags: identify-this-game

I can remember below pointers off the top of my head:

- It was an adventurous game
- We had to cross different levels (can relate to Mario for instance)
- The protagonist was short and was wearing a cop hat with black or dark blue uniform
- One of the stages had a lot of greenery and river

I am sorry, that's all I can recall as of now.

EDIT:

- I was playing the game in TV a video game. It was during 90s and I used NES or Sega games.
- The game was delightful and was having daylight time during their stages. I also remember there was a scene with huge waterfall in the background
- I remember it was about climing difficult heights, jumping and even killing the small enemies which were in animal form. Like we did in Mario.

Comment: Can you remember on what system you played the game?

Comment: I played that on TV. It was either nes or sega (truly sorry for not remembering in details)

Comment: Please add that information (and whatever else there may be to restrict search) to the question.

Comment: @RaviManiyar What was the controller like? Computer keyboard? Atari-like? Joystick? Handheld? Buttons?

Comment: @Raffzahn added more info

Comment: @wizzwizz4 it was TV video game

Comment: You may have better/quicker luck here: https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/

Comment: There's also an `#identify-a-game` channel on the MobyGames Discord.

Comment: How is it of any help that ‘the game was delightful’? Knowing whether you liked the game or not doesn’t narrow the space of possibilities at all.

Comment: @user3840170 Given the context it's used in, "the game was delightful" is probably an English as a Second Language slip-up when the intent was to say something a bit more objective like "the game was cheerful".

Answer (score 4):

I'll make a first guess, and then we can refine it from there as you remember more about the game.

A platform game about men in dark uniforms seems to me to be [***The Blues Brothers*** by Titus](http://superadventuresingaming.blogspot.com/2011/08/blues-brothers-c64.html). It was released for almost all the 8-bit and 16-bit console and computer platforms of the day.

[image]

It's based on the movie of the same name. You play as one of The Blues Brothers (or both in two-player), 'Joliet' Jake and Elwood Blues - famous for only ever wearing a basic black suit, sunglasses and hat - as they jump around various locations attempting to recover all the instruments needed for the big concert to save their orphanage. Your character is the man on the left. There's large floating LP records that you can collect to earn extra hit-points.

There's a sequel, *The Blues Brothers: Jukebox Adventure*, which you may also be thinking of.

Comment: hey buddy, thanks for the details. But unfortunately its not the one I am looking for. This one seems little dark, the one I am looking is more delightful and was having daylight time during their stages.

I also remember there was a scene with huge waterfall in the background. But indeed the main character was wearing uniform and hat.

Comment: @RaviManiyar Given, I'm not a gamer, but I had to try that one back in the days (Atari ST). I do remember Blues Brothers as a rather light hearted game - at least when knowing the movie as well :)

Comment: @Raffzahn -- haha. Yeah never heard about the game nor movie. But the images seem its a little dark. But the game I played was quite delightful and in fact funny at some times.

Comment: @RaviManiyar WHAT? Go to your next Blockbuster ... err ... DVD-Shop .... err Download portal, get the movie and watch it. DO NOT WAIT. GO. WATCH IT. (Not sorry for going off topic when it's about the Blues Brothers - one of the few to be watched multiple times on purpose) :))

Comment: @Raffzahn gotcha :)

Comment: If @Raffzahn tells you to do something, you do it.

Comment: @knol - any other thoughts? :|

Comment: @RaviManiyar We need more information.

Comment: @knol upon some stress, I remember it was about climing difficult heights, jumping and even killing the small enemies which were in animal form. Like we did in Mario.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's one of the Livingstone games? The first is from 1986:

[image]

Livingstone Supongo II:
[image]

The Search for Dr. Livingston (NES) 1992:
[image]

Comment: Has that ever been ported to a console?

Comment: @Raffzahn IDK, but it might be the later "The Search for Dr. Livingston" on NES, added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, but it really sounds like Pitfall II. It came out for different platforms, although I played it at an arcade room.

A video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSWP7QilfCI

[image: A screenshot]

Comment: Oh no, sorry mate - this isn't I am looking forward to :( - do you have any other suggestions in mind please?